# Prevent figures/listings from being inserted into specific parts of a LaTeX document

Tags: layout, latex, figures

I have a part A in a document with some text and listings/figures in between. The figures and listings are positioned using `htb`.

Following this part A, there is the bibliography. However a couple of figures do not fit and are therefore are offset to another page, which is fine. But: I do want to limit the offset space to part A and not have the figures be placed within the bibliography text. Also, I don't want to force page of float for all figures (`hp` positioning or something). A page of floats at the end of part A and before the bibliography would be fine.

So my questions is, is there a way to exclude some parts of a LaTex document from being used for positioning floats that did not fit someplace before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but couldn't you just put a `\clearpage` right before the bibliography?  That forces out all floats that haven't found a place yet.

Comment: No - you are absolutely right, I was hung up on `\eject` and `\newpage` but totally oversaw this one. Thanks.